# Apollo GraphQL server not responding when Include Cookies is turned on

Tags: node.js, typescript, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

Whenever I set the "Include Cookies" option as "On", the graphql server says that the server is not responding.

[image]

This works fine if the option is "Off".

Here is the `index.ts`

```
const main = async () => {
  const mikroOrmConfig = {
    debug: true,
    user: 'postgres',
    entities: [Post, User],
    type: 'postgresql',
    dbName: 'lireddit',
    password: 'graphql',
    allowGlobalContext: true,
    migrations: {
      path: path.join(__dirname, './migrations'),
      pattern: /^[\w-]+\d+\.[tj]s$/
    }
  } as Parameters<typeof MikroORM.init>[0];

  const orm = await MikroORM.init(mikroOrmConfig);

  const app = express();
  app.use(cors())

  const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
    schema: await buildSchema({
      resolvers: [PostResolver, UserResolver],
      validate: false
    }),
    context: ({ req, res }): MyContext => ({ em: orm.em, req, res })
  });

  await apolloServer.start();

  apolloServer.applyMiddleware({ app })
  
  app.listen(4000, () => {
    console.log("Server started at port 4000")
  })
};

main().catch(err => console.error(err));
```

I get the following error if I try to hit an API:

```
{
"name": "TypeError",
"message": "Failed to fetch",
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update:
Setting this to the server worked:

```
  app.set('trust proxy', true)

  app.use(
    cors({
      credentials: true,
      origin: [
        "https://studio.apollographql.com",
        "http://localhost:4000/graphql",
      ],
    })
  );
```

Also, needed to attach this header in the request:

[image]